# Facebook Comments Box/ Twitter Feed broken in angular/symfony web app

Tags: facebook, symfony, angularjs, twitter

I am attempting to build a site using angularJS and symfony, and in my site
I want to add a simple Facebook comments box and twitter timeline shown here, respectively:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/comments/
https://twitter.com/settings/widgets/370693822461657088/edit?focus_textarea=1&notice=WIDGET_CREATED

in my JavaScript i have set up angular routing which routes the user to different views, but the problem is the comments box and twitter timeline don't show up in these views.

They DO however, work perfectly fine when they are placed outside of the ng-view tags.

Here is a VERY simplified code snippet of my problem:

```
<html ng-app="myApp">
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <title>{% block title %}Welcome!{% endblock %}</title>

        {% block custom_stylesheets %}
        {% endblock %}
    </head>

    <body>
        {% block body %}
    <div id = "container">
        <!-- twitter and facebook work outside of here -->
        <div ng-view>
            <!-- but not in here -->
        </div>
    </div>
        {% endblock %}

    {% block custom_javascripts %}
        {% endblock %}
    </body>
</html>
```

Is there something specific i need to do to get twitter/facebook working?
it seems as if the javascript is broken, the twitter feed still displays a "tweets by @google" link

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need directives because the JavaScript needs to execute whenever some set of DOM elements is present:

```
(function() {
  var createDirective, module, pluginName, _i, _len, _ref;

  module = angular.module('FacebookPluginDirectives', []);

  createDirective = function(name) {
    return module.directive(name, function() {
      return {
        restrict: 'C',
        link: function(scope, element, attributes) {
          return typeof FB !== "undefined" && FB !== null ? FB.XFBML.parse(element.parent()[0]) : void 0;
        }
      };
    });
  };

  _ref = ['fbActivity', 'fbComments', 'fbFacepile', 'fbLike', 'fbLikeBox', 'fbLiveStream', 'fbLoginButton', 'fbName', 'fbProfilePic', 'fbRecommendations'];
  for (_i = 0, _len = _ref.length; _i < _len; _i++) {
    pluginName = _ref[_i];
    createDirective(pluginName);
  }

}).call(this);
```

I found this one on the internets that handles the Facebook one's in a pretty simple way I believe the definition even stays the same as the original usage, you just do something like:

```
<div class="fb-comments" data-href="http://pyramidplayersproductions.org" data-width="292" data-num-posts="10"></div><br/>
<div class="fb-like-box" data-href="http://www.facebook.com/pyramidplayersproductions" data-width="292" data-show-faces="true" data-stream="true" data-show-border="true" data-header="true"></div>
```

You'll still have to roll your own for the twitter feed (or search google for Angular twitter directive and see what surfaces).  If nothing does the general formula for building a directive will be:

```
angular.module("customDirectives", []).directive("myTwitterDirective", function() {
          return {
            //C means class E means element A means attribute, this is where this directive should be found
            restrict: 'E',
            link: function(scope, element, attributes) {
              //do javascript you need to here to get data or initialize
              //twitter.  you can access the dom element using element[0]
              //element is the angular wrapped element object attributes
              //has any HTML attributes like attribute.myAttribute would be 'something if <my-twitter-directive myAttribute='something'>
            }
          };
        });


//probably in another file
angular.module("mainApp", ["customDirectives"]);
```

Usage would look like:

```
<my-twitter-directive></my-twitter-directive>
```

Wrapping this stuff up in a directive keeps the DOM manipulation code out of the services or controllers (and presentation) code, keeping all of them easily testable without the need for an actual browser or dependencies on the view.

I decided to follow my own advice above and I think I'm right:

http://jsfiddle.net/MPnES/

The JS

```
angular.module("mainApp", []).directive("twitterTimeline", function() {
          return {
            //C means class E means element A means attribute, this is where this directive should be found
            restrict: 'C',
            link: function(scope, element, attributes) {

                !function(d,s,id){var js,fjs=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],p=/^http:/.test(d.location)?'http':'https';if(!d.getElementById(id)){js=d.createElement(s);js.id=id;js.src=p+"://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js";fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js,fjs);}}(document,"script","twitter-wjs");
            }
          };
        });
```

The HTML

```
<body ng-app="mainApp">
<a class="twitter-timeline" href="https://twitter.com/pattonoswalt" data-widget-id="370757361348014081">
Tweets by @pattonoswalt
</a>
</body>
```

Comment: I implemented the twitter timeline directive you wrote into my page, and it seems to work, but only the FIRST time the partial view is loaded.  If i load another view and then return to the same partial view the facebook comments box and timeline are broken again. Do you have any idea what might possibly be happening?  Thank you for writing such a detailed response! I appreciate it.

Comment: the problem was due to the problem that angular does not support loading script tags in partial views natively via jqlite.  importing jquery before angular solved my problem.
More on this here: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/angular/H4haaMePJU0

Comment: Was out of town glad you got it sorted is there something I should add to the answer?